# Nested Data grid using ASP.Net 1.1 controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid, export-to-excel, .net-1.1

Has anyone worked on creating the **Nested Data grids in ASP.Net 1.1**?

Outer Grid: I would like to have the rows to be expandable.  On click of **"+"** on each row, I would like the inner data grid to be populated with certain values based on that row.

Also export to excel feature for all of them in the same format.

I'm getting it using jQuery but looking for possible options in ASP.Net 1.1 controls itself.

Comment: What have you tried? What means _"values based on Row 1"_? Export to excel seems to be a different question and should be asked separately since it's better to export the datasource instead of the grid anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking "How can I do this using just ASP.NET 1.1?" the answer is simple:  you can't.  Nothing remotely like that is built into ASP.NET 1.1, except perhaps in third-party controls (but good luck finding the 1.1 versions at this point.)

On the bright side, however, you won't have to deal with Microsoft Ajax features in 1.1, which means that the page model is more straightforward.

If your jQuery solution is working for you, there's not a strong case to be made for going farther.  But if you want something more of a black box, that's reusable and automatically injects the jQuery code, you could subclass the DataGrid and write code to emit javascript code blocks containing your jQuery code.